# textarea append jquery to iframe not working

Tags: jquery, iframe, editor

```
<script>
function full(){
return $('.iframes').contents().find('body').html($('.value').val());
}
</script>

<textarea class="value"></textarea>
<button onClick="full();">click</button>
<iframe class='iframes'></iframe>
```

am trying to create online editor for jquery so first i create

```
<textarea class="value"></textarea>
<button onClick="full();">click</button>
<iframe class='iframes'></iframe>
```

and jquery is

```
function full(){
return $('.iframes').contents().find('body').html($('.value').val());
}
```

when i type anything in textarea it's appended to iframes but my issue is when i type jquery function inside textarea like that

```
<p id="demo">test</p>
<button onclick="fff();">Click Me!</button>
<script>
function fff() {
$('#demo').text('my name is');
}
</script>
```

the jquery not working . is there away to make it work inside iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was the dom so i write this code and work just fine

```
<textarea id="mytext" onKeyUp="fff();"></textarea>
<div id="sss"></div>
<script>
function fff() {
    var text = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
    var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifr.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    ifr.setAttribute("id", "iframeResult");
    document.getElementById("sss").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("sss").appendChild(ifr);
    var ifrw = (ifr.contentWindow) ? ifr.contentWindow :
    (ifr.contentDocument.document) ? ifr.contentDocument.document : ifr.contentDocument;
    ifrw.document.open();
    ifrw.document.write(text);
    ifrw.document.close();
    if (ifrw.document.body && !ifrw.document.body.isContentEditable) {
        ifrw.document.body.contentEditable = true;
        ifrw.document.body.contentEditable = false;
    }
}
</script>
```